# Set like with Instagram api

Tags: ios, swift, api, instagram, alamofire

I am building an ios app with Instagram App and I wanted to set like on a post

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' \
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes
```

How to make this curl request using Alamofire in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Alamofire tutorial on Github:](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers)

Here's how to create a POST Request With HTTP Headers:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/headers", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Now, for creating a POST to the Instagram API:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "access_token": \(YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN)
]

Alamofire.request("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/\(media-id)/likes", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
}

// you could also explicitly define the request as a POST
Alamofire.request("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/\(media-id)/likes", method: .post, headers: headers)
```

**EDIT #1:**

Changed code slightly to reflect OP's working solution.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "access_token": \(YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN)
]

Alamofire.request("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/\(media-id)/likes", method: .post, parameters: header).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: I making request but it says that it is missing access token, I am using alamofire with response json

Comment: Never mind I did it by myself. I have changed **headers** to **parameters** and added **method: .post** and it started working!